# Pass value to methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im total new to Vue so be kind :)

I have a function that gets the user attributes and based on the attribute i avant to run a graphql query on another function. Both functions are in methods and get called on created life cycle. What i did is to assign it to a variable and render it in the DOM. But i cant get to pass it in the function i want. I tried running each function in different lifecycle hook but it didn't help.

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'IndexPage',
  data: function() {
    return {
      token: '',
      redirectUrl: '',
      authUser: ''
    }
  },
  methods:{
    async setUser() {
      this.authUser = authUser
    },
    async getAtt() {
        Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
        .then(data => (this.authUser = data.attributes['custom:learn_url']))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    },
    async getUrl() {
      const id = this.authUser; // This is where i want the id to assign the authUser value
      const learnUrl = await API.graphql({
        variables: { id },
        query: getLearnUrl
      });
      this.redirectUrl = learnUrl.data.getLearnUrl.learnUrl;
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getAtt();
    this.getUrl();
  }
})
```

Comment: Where is `getLearnUrl`? Shouldn't this also be `this.getLearnUrl` instead?

Comment: Thats a imported variable `import { getLearnUrl } from '../graphql/custom-queries';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem could lie in your `created()` method. It's calling an async method `getAtt()`, so you need to wait for it to complete before you can use the `authUser` variable you got previously in the `getUrl()` function, otherwise, it will always be empty.

Change `created()` to async, and await for the functions.

### Example

```
async created() {
  await this.getAtt();
  await this.getUrl();
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that will be enough to await the getAtt() function. OP should also place `await` before the `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then...` part if they want the value of `this.authUser` to be set before `getUrl` is called. Alternatively they could return that same line for the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Tamas' suggestion you will need to await the result of the `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` function as well.

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'IndexPage',
  data: function() {
    return {
      token: '',
      redirectUrl: '',
      authUser: ''
    }
  },
  methods:{
    async setUser() {
      this.authUser = authUser
    },
    async getAtt() {
        await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() // 
        .then(data => (this.authUser = data.attributes['custom:learn_url']))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    },
    async getUrl() {
      const id = this.authUser; // This is where i want the id to assign the authUser value
      const learnUrl = await API.graphql({
        variables: { id },
        query: getLearnUrl
      });
      this.redirectUrl = learnUrl.data.getLearnUrl.learnUrl;
    }
  },
  async created() {
    await this.getAtt();
    this.getUrl();
  }
})
```